# Select numbered Distinct values from Sql Server column

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have a Sql Server query as:

```
SELECT  AC.Author_ID, A.Author_Name, AC.Paper_ID, AC.CoAuthor_ID, AP.Venue_ID, AC.Year
FROM    AuthorCoAuthor  AC
JOIN    AuthorPaper     AP ON AP.Author_ID  = AC.Author_ID AND 
                        AP.Paper_ID = AC.Paper_ID
JOIN    Author          A  ON A.Author_ID   = AC.Author_ID
ORDER BY AC.Author_ID, AC.Year, AC.Paper_ID, AC.CoAuthor_ID, AP.Venue_ID
```

which returns almost 221317 rows. The sample output is:

```
Author_ID | Author_Name | Paper_ID | CoAuthor_ID | Venue_ID | Year  
------------------------------------------------------------------
677       | Nuno Vasc   | 812229   | 901706      | 64309    | 2005
677       | Nuno Vasc   | 812486   | 901706      | 65182    | 2005
677       | Nuno Vasc   | 818273   | 901706      | 185787   | 2007  
1359      | Peng Sui    | 818373   | 457348      | 18534    | 2005  
1359      | Peng Sui    | 868273   | 542321      | 184222   | 2006  
...       | ...         | ...      | ...         | ...      | ...
```

I want to have only 10 distinct `Author_ID` to be returned by the query, whereas I tried by adding

```
WHERE  COUNT(DISTINCT(AC.Author_ID)) <= 10
```

this `WHERE` clause into the same query but still I'm getting same number of rows i.e. all the data which normally query returns.

Why my `WHERE` clause not working here?

Comment: Which 10 author IDs  Top 10?   Random 10?  Top Sequential?

Comment: Top Sequential IDs

Comment: Then Matjedi got ot

Comment: He posted an answer

Comment: Sorry ... on my phone and don't have my glasses.   Sucks getting old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 10 Distinct `Author_ID`, you can use **GROUP BY** with **TOP 10**. Then join the result (10 rows here) with other tables to show columns you want, in the `select list`.

You can try this:

```
SELECT AC.Author_ID, A.Author_Name, AC.Paper_ID, AC.CoAuthor_ID, AP.Venue_ID, AC.Year
FROM
(
   SELECT TOP (10) AC.Author_ID
   FROM AuthorCoAuthor AC
   GROUP BY AC.Author_ID
   ORDER BY AC.Author_ID
) DS
JOIN AuthorCoAuthor  AC ON AC.Author_ID = DS.Author_ID
JOIN    AuthorPaper     AP ON AP.Author_ID  = AC.Author_ID AND 
                    AP.Paper_ID = AC.Paper_ID
JOIN    Author          A  ON A.Author_ID   = AC.Author_ID
ORDER BY AC.Author_ID, AC.Year, AC.Paper_ID, AC.CoAuthor_ID, AP.Venue_ID
```

**UPDATE**

By the Previous Answer, You can get less than `10 Distinct Author` if both `AuthorPaper` & `Author` table doesn't have one of those Top 10 Sequential Author. For that reason, you need to check those condition when you get `10 Distinct Author` so that it always give you `10 Distinct Author` if and only if `AuthorCoAuthor` has at least `10 Distinct Author`. So, To make sure, you always get `10 Distinct Author`, you can use this one:

```
SELECT AC.Author_ID, A.Author_Name, AC.Paper_ID, AC.CoAuthor_ID, AP.Venue_ID, AC.Year
FROM
(
   SELECT TOP (10) AC.Author_ID
   FROM AuthorCoAuthor AC
   JOIN AuthorPaper AP 
      ON AP.Author_ID  = AC.Author_ID 
         AND AP.Paper_ID = AC.Paper_ID
   JOIN Author A  ON A.Author_ID = AC.Author_ID
   GROUP BY AC.Author_ID
   ORDER BY AC.Author_ID
) DS
JOIN AuthorCoAuthor  AC ON AC.Author_ID = DS.Author_ID
JOIN AuthorPaper AP 
   ON AP.Author_ID  = AC.Author_ID 
      AND AP.Paper_ID = AC.Paper_ID
JOIN Author A  ON A.Author_ID = AC.Author_ID
ORDER BY AC.Author_ID, AC.Year, AC.Paper_ID, AC.CoAuthor_ID, AP.Venue_ID
```

Comment: Not allowing me to use DISTINCT keyword with TOP(10) here

Comment: Updated the Answer. Check Now.